# Encoding in Lua like Python(ord function)

Tags: python, lua

I want to translate below code segment in Lua:

```
def toLong(s):
  ls = [ord(i) for i in s]
  l = len(ls) -1
  sum = 0
  for i, v in enumerate(ls):
      sum += v*(256**(l-i))
  return sum

print(toLong("\x00\x00\x01f\xd3d\x80X"))
```

it prints the original number: **1541144871000**

Comment: Lua (unlike Python) is unable to work with very long integers (unless you have some external library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works with lua 5.2 if you install [bigint](https://github.com/JorjBauer/lua-bigint):

```
local bigint = require "bigint"

function toLong(s) 
    ret = bigint:new(0)
    for i=1,string.len(s),1 do
        -- (leftshift(8) is just like times-256, but faster)
        ret = ret:leftshift(8) + bigint:new(string.byte(s, i))
    end
    return ret
end
```

Prior to lua 5.2, the "\xAB"-style syntax wasn't supported, but you could do decimals like "\65" for an ASCII capital A.

BTW, you *can* do this without bigint like:

```
function numLong(s)
    ret = 0
    for i=1,string.len(s),1 do
        ret = (ret * 256) + string.byte(s,i)
    end
    return ret
end
```

The big difference is that bigint will represent arbitrarily large numbers and the normal number value is a float by default in Lua and has a precision limit on the number of bits that are actually usable (though on my machine, the two representations come out the same when I tested your specific case).

That said: if you need arbitrarily-large number representation, use bigint or go insane.

Oh, BTW:  You do realize you're using big-endian (or "network byte order") in calculating your numbers, right?  Do be careful swapping between char strings and uint64s (especially if your target machine is little-endian like an Intel box)...